# Executing Pig Script Remotely

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I am trying to execute **pig** scripts from **java** so that it can connect to the cluster and execute the logic. I am following [this](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/setup.html#Sample+Code) link, but how this is going to connect my cluster as i am not mentioning the **URL**. How can i connect it remotely ?

**Code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;
public class idlocal{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("local");
        runIdQuery(pigServer, "passwd");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
    public static void runIdQuery(PigServer pigServer, String inputFile) throws IOException {
        pigServer.registerQuery("A = load '" + inputFile + "' using PigStorage(':');");
        pigServer.registerQuery("B = foreach A generate $0 as id;");
        pigServer.store("B", "id.out");
    }
}
```

Comment: Without trying this, the logical place to put the link would be where you define the PigServer.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin can you please give some more explanation.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin i tried adding `Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("fs.default.name", "hdfs://hdfs://192.168.x.xxx:8022");
    props.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", "192.168.x.xxx:8021");` also but it didn't work

Comment: I was not able to find much, but probably "local" should be replaced with some other mode.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin i tried Mapreduce way also but getting error.
please check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574653/error-executing-pigserver-in-java)