# Error executing PigServer in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I am trying to run pig scripts remotely from my java machine, for that i have written below code

**code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;

public class Javapig{ 
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("fs.default.name", "hdfs://hdfs://192.168.x.xxx:8022");
    props.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", "192.168.x.xxx:8021");

    PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE, props);
    runIdQuery(pigServer, "fact");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
 }
public static void runIdQuery(PigServer pigServer, String inputFile) throws IOException {
    pigServer.registerQuery("A = load '" + inputFile + "' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();");
    pigServer.registerQuery("B = FILTER A by category == 'Aller';");
    pigServer.registerQuery("DUMP B;");
    System.out.println("Done");
 }
}
```

but while executing i am getting below error.

**Error**

```
ERROR 4010: Cannot find hadoop configurations in classpath (neither hadoop-site.xml nor core-site.xml was found in the classpath).
```

I don't know what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, self describing error...

> neither hadoop-site.xml nor core-site.xml was found in the classpath

You need both of those files in the classpath of your application.

You ideally would get those from your `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` folder, and you would copy them into your Java's `src/main/resources`, assuming you have a Maven structure

Also, with those files, you should rather use a `Configuration` object for Hadoop

```
PigServer(ExecType execType, org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf)
```